# linq query cant seem to see my model

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

there are 5 properties in my InventoryGridModel, and I get an error on every one, saying the model does not contain that property.  Obviously the model does, so not sure what is going on, is like the code cant read the model.

model:

```
 public class InstrumentGridModel
 {
     public int InstrumentId { get; set; }
     public string ItemName { get; set; }
     public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
     public string CaseNumber { get; set; }
     public string LocationName { get; set; }
     public string SiteCode { get; set; }
 }
```

method that is supposed to pull the info from db and populate the model:

```
    public List<InstrumentGridModel> GetInstruments()
    {
        var results = new List<InstrumentGridModel>();
        var data = from i in db.Instrument
                   join l in db.Location on i.LocationId equals l.LocationId
                   join t in db.InventoryItem on i.ItemId equals t.ItemId
                   select new InstrumentGridModel
                   {
                       InstrumentId = i.InstrumentId,
                       ItemName = t.ItemName,
                       SerialNumber = i.SerialNumber,
                       CaseNumber = i.CaseNumber,
                       LocationName = l.LocationName
                   };

        foreach (var i in data)
        {
            results.Add(new InstrumentGridModel()
            {
                InstrumentId = data.InstrumentId,
                ItemName = data.ItemName,
                SerialNumber = data.SerialNumber,
                CaseNumber = data.CaseNumber,
                LocationName = data.LocationName
            });
        }
        return results;

    }
```

error (note this is just one error, I get the same error on all 5 properties):

```
Error   3   'System.Linq.IQueryable<MusicInventory.Models.InstrumentGridModel>' does not contain a definition for 'ItemName' and no extension method 'ItemName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MusicInventory.Models.InstrumentGridModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: `InstrumentId = data.InstrumentId,` should be `InstrumentId = i.InstrumentId,` (data is the collection which does not contain a property named `InstrumentId`.

Comment: Note also you don't need the `foreach` loop. you can just use `var data = from i in db.Instrument ... select new InstrumentGridModel {InstrumentId = i.InstrumentId, .....}.ToList(); return data;`

Comment: @Stephen.  I thought so to, but I can't get it to work with out the foreach, I get an error "MusicInventory.Models.InstrumentGridModel' does not contain a definition for 'ToList'..." Ideas?

Comment: Sorry, needs parenthesis `var data = (from ...}).ToList();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over `data` in the foreach-loop. You then however access `data` (which is of type `System.Linq.IQueryable<MusicInventory.Models.InstrumentGridModel>` I guess). What you want to do however is use ì`in the loop instead of`data`, i.e. access the single item, not the collection.